# Continuous WebJob don't start

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

I'm trying to deploy Continuous WebJob (.NET Core 3.1) that have a function with NoAutomaticTrigger attribute. Here is my code.

```cs
[NoAutomaticTrigger]
public async Task StartProcessingTest(ILogger logger)
{
    await FindActiveContainers(logger);
}
```

The main method:

```cs
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    _configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
        .Build();

    var builder = new HostBuilder();

    builder.ConfigureWebJobs(b => b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices());
    builder.ConfigureLogging(b =>
    {
        b.AddConsole();
    });
    builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.AddSingleton(_configuration);
        services.BuildServiceProvider();
    });

    var host = builder.Build();
    using (host)
    {
        await host.RunAsync();
    }
}
```

As I can see the job starts without any exceptions, but for some reasons, the function StartProcessingTest didn't trigger at the start.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you didn't **invoke** your StartProcessingTest function in your main code.

If the problem still exist, check if you publish the connectionstring.

Here is the [official document about manual trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-how-to#manual-triggers).

You could invoke like this:

```
 await jobHost.CallAsync("CreateQueueMessage", inputs);
```